# How should I code my jQuery so when I hover over my div, the image in it dissolves into another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I need to use the hover function on the div, then change the images src attribute, but I don't know how to make it dissolve from one to the other. If I hide it, it just fades back in from white. But I want it to dissolve image to image.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jquery tutorial:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

HTML

```
<div class="fade">
  <a href="/info.html"><img src="start.jpg" /></a>
  <div>
    <a href="/info.html"><img src="end.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

Obviously if I had more than one fading image, I would use an ID or alternative class to position the top and left CSS properties.

```
.fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px
  left: 100px
}

.fade div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
// when the DOM is ready:
$(document).ready(function () {
  // find the div.fade elements and hook the hover event
  $('div.fade').hover(function() {
    // on hovering over, find the element we want to fade *up*
    var fade = $('> div', this);

    // if the element is currently being animated (to a fadeOut)...
    if (fade.is(':animated')) {
      // ...take it's current opacity back up to 1
      fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
    } else {
      // fade in quickly
      fade.fadeIn(250);
    }
  }, function () {
    // on hovering out, fade the element out
    var fade = $('> div', this);
    if (fade.is(':animated')) {
      fade.stop().fadeTo(3000, 0);
    } else {
      // fade away slowly
      fade.fadeOut(3000);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery UI library - in particular, its `show` features

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="hoverme"><img class="still" src="..." /><img class="hstate" src="..." /></div>
```

css, set your div  height/width &

```
        .hoverm {position:relative; width:100px;height:100px;}

       .hoverme img {display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
       .hoverme img.hstate {display:none;}
```

js

```
       $(document).on({"mouseover":function() {
                          $(this).find(".hstate").stop().fadeIn(500);
                          },
                       "mouseout":function() {
                          $(this).find(".hstate").stop().fadeOut(500);
                       }, ".hoverme");
```